# I cannot create new class with WindowBuilder plugin on eclipse oxigen

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I am a Java noob and I've just heard about the WindowBuilder plugin and I want to try it. I've installed the plugin from the Help->Eclipse marketplace menu item as you can see in the first screenshot below.
My problem, that I cannot create this kind of class in an empty project, because the 'WindowBuilder' menu item, which has to be in the list is not visible and I don't know why. There wasn't any error messages during or after the install.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

[image: my photo from the plugin]
[image: the menu item which I'm looking for is missing]

Comment: Open the About-window (Help -> About Eclipse) and click on the "Installation Details" button. Do you see the entries for WindowBuilder? What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Hi! Yeah, I see some 'WindowBuilder...*' entries such as WindowBuilder Core and some Swing... and SWT... entries. I'm using the newest, eclipse oxigen, as I mentioned in the title.

Comment: Hm, out of ideas other than checking Eclipse's logfile if you see error in there that prevent WindowBuilder from starting.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!

I just deceded to write the solution which is worked for me. I hope it will be useful for somebody.
   First uninstall the previously install things: Help->Eclipse Marketplace->Installed->Uninstall

After that just do the same as this guy doing in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cit_c5LVw0Y

I don't know why, but from the eclipse marketplace it isn't working, but from help->install new software it works :D It's crazy, but at least I figured out....